# UML Diagram Solidity

Tags: solidity

How can modifiers be shown in a Solidity UML-Diagram, next to the access modifier -+#~. Do you know to visualize this kind of modifier?

```
modifier onlyProducer(){
        if(msg.sender != producer){
             throw;
        }
        _;
}
```

Comment: Like public/private method?

Comment: more like extended version of public/private